# How can I embed multiple column with Active Model Serializers in Rails?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, active-model-serializers

I have a

UserList model & UserListMovie. UserList has_many movies, through: :user_list_movies.

Originally in my serializer for UserList, I only needed to embed the user_list_movies_id.

```
class Api::V1::UserTeamSerializer < ActiveModel::Serializer
  ...
  has_many :movies, embed: :ids
  ...
end
```

This obviously worked just fine.

However, I recently added a column to user_list_movies which is sort_order. When UserList is requested, I want to return both user_list_movie_id's and their respective sort_order's.

How can I do this? How can I include both of these values in the serializer? Or do I need to go about this another way?

Answer (score 0):

The simplest way to do this is to create another serializer, maybe you could call it the MovieSerializer, which would receive a movie object.

```
class Api::V1::MovieSerializer < ActiveModel::Serializer

  attributes :id, :sort_order

end
```

Then you specify that serializer in your `UserTeamSerializer`:

```
class Api::V1::UserTeamSerializer < ActiveModel::Serializer
  ...
  has_many :movies, serializer: Api::V1::MovieSerializer
  ...
end
```

That will return an array of serialized movie objects, each with an `id` and a `sort_order`.

Does that answer your question?